# Unit used for ffmpeg x and y

Tags: ffmpeg

What is the unit used for the ffmpeg command line below:

```
ffmpeg -i 001-Original.mp4 -strict experimental -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSansBold.ttf:text=www.al.com:x=5:y=30
```

x=5 and y=30 are they in pixels?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes they're in pixels.

Comment: I measured that with pixel ruler, it is giving me a wrong result

Comment: Can you post a snapshot (one frame)?

Comment: it works aergistal, thanks, I took a measurment from the bottom of the word not from the top of it